# Moment date is working in Chrome not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I am allowing the user to add a date manually in the date field. 
If the user enters the date as 1/1/13 I am expecting a result as 01/01/2013.
This is what I am using.
**Code:**

```
moment("1/1/13").format('MM/DD/YYYY')
```

In chrome it is working fine but not working in FF and IE it shows 01/01/1913 instead of 01/01/2013.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1410pbev/25/)

Comment: I am allowing them to add mm/dd/yyyy and mm/dd/yy @Hebele

Answer (score 1):

You need to give `moment` the format of the data it's parsing, using [`moment(string, string)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/). In fact, if you look in your web console, `moment` is telling you that:

> Deprecation warning: `moment` construction falls back to js `Date`. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.

So:

```
moment("1/1/13", "M/D/YY").format("MM/DD/YYYY");
//             ^^^^^^^^^^----- the format to parse with
```

...assuming the date is in month/day/year order (since that's what you're outputting).

Example *(I've changed the date slightly so we can tell days from months)*:

```js
console.log(moment("1/2/13", "M/D/YY").format("MM/DD/YYYY"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

In a comment you've said:

> I am allowing them to add mm/dd/yyyy and mm/dd/yy format. this is not working for 1/1/1999

See the docs linked above, if you want to support a variable number of digits in the year, use `YYYY` for the year:

```js
console.log(moment("1/2/13", "M/D/YYYY").format("MM/DD/YYYY"));
console.log(moment("1/2/1999", "M/D/YYYY").format("MM/DD/YYYY"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am allowing them to add mm/dd/yyyy and mm/dd/yy format. this is not working for 1/1/1999

Comment: @SrinivasPai use a single Y for your year token and it will work. That matches both 2 and 4 digit years. Alternately, you can also pass an array of formats.

Comment: @MaggiePint: If you use just a single Y, it'll parse "13" as the year 13 (not 2013).

Comment: @SrinivasPai: I've updated the answer. It's important to include information like that in the question.

Comment: @t.j.crowder you are totally correct. It seems I have temporarily forgotten how to use my own library. :-)

Comment: @MaggiePint: LOL! We've all done things like that... :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is because Moment.js uses the `Date` object when creating a new moment, and unfortunately that works differently in Firefox and Chrome.

To test it simply try creating a new date in both browsers.

```
new Date('1/1/13');
```

Frankly, I am surprised that Chrome interprets this as 2013. To be safe and cross-browser compliant, just write out the full year. If you are getting this from an outside source, you should simply be able to parse it and reformat it to a safer shortened ISO format like so:

```
dateString.replace(/^(\d\d?)\/(\d\d?)\/(\d\d{2,4})$/, (day, month, year) => {
  day = day.length === 1 ? '0' + day : day;
  month = month.length === 1 ? '0' + month : month;
  year = year.length === 2 ? '20' + year : year;

  if (year.length === 3) {
    throw new Error('Invalid date format. Year must either be 2 or 4 characters long.);
  }

  return [day, '-', month, '-', year].join('');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working perfectly in Chrome and Mozilla

```
moment(`${day}/${month}/${year}`, "DD/MMM/YYYY").format("MMMM/DD/YYYY");
//January/01/2021
```